Parsing and understanding PaliGemma Image Segmentation
PaliGemma returns the following output for segmentation of an image:
<loc0048><loc0105><loc1023><loc1023><seg077><seg108><seg045><seg028><seg056><seg031><seg114><seg109><seg042><seg026><seg084><seg092><seg086><seg077><seg090><seg056>
I understand the first 4 <locxxxx> entries are the coordinates of the bounding box, and from here I understand how to convert them into proper coordinates:
https://huggingface.co/blog/paligemma
But I have been completely unable to deal with the segmentation mask. I can find no documentation that hints even slightly at how one would interpret those numbers, I brute-forced every approach I could think of, but nothing came up with a proper mask.
Seldom have I felt so dumb in my life, certainly this is obvious and I am just missing something that literally every other sentient being on earth understands?

This question was asked forever ago, but for posterity and in case you still want an answer, PaliGemma's segmentation outputs are special "soft" tokens that come from a special visual encoder described here.
To parse them into meaningful coordinates, Google has an example here.
